# Retrieving links and names of images from a NextGEN gallery

Tags: plugins, gallery, plugin-nextgen-gallery

I want to add a list (like a cd track list) of names and links to all images next my nextgen gallery, how can I retrieve this list? (similar to the list in the select object in the Gallery Settings, in the gallery admin page)

Comment: Where do you get the data from?

Comment: hmmm I thought that there might be a shortcode for that.. right now I simply use a gallery shortcode in a post. I want to add it to the imagebrowser.php template, a simple list of all images in that gallery..

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this has worked for me.

```
<?php 
// get the track list 
global $nggdb;
    $gallery = $nggdb->get_gallery ($galleryID, 'sortorder', 'ASC', true, 0, 0);
?>
<div id="tracklist">
<?php foreach($gallery as $image) { ?>
<div class="single_image" id="image-<?php echo $image->pid; ?>">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>&pid=<?php echo $image->pid;?>" title="<?php echo $image->title; ?>">
        <?php echo $image->alttext; ?>
    </a>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use a function similar to below one to retrieve a list of image properties in a Next-Gen image gallery.

```
function wp75475_imagelist(){

//http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );

if(!is_plugin_active('nextgen-gallery/nggallery.php')){
    return 'NextGen Gallery Plugin is needed to display imagelist';
}

$imagegallery = new nggdb();
$images = $imagegallery->get_gallery('cdtrack');
$imagelist = '';

foreach ($images as $image):
    $imagelist .= $image->$filename;
endforeach;

return $imagelist;

}
```

For a list of retrievable image properties see properties of nggImage object.

> /nextgen-gallery/lib/image.php

Comment: Thanks Upeksha, can I use it in imagebrowser.php ?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. (in /yourthemefolder/nggallery/imagebrowser.php)

Comment: I'm trying, getting no errors, but it doesn't print anything... I wrapped the code with <?php code ?> and put it at the top of the page, right below <div class="ngg-imagebrowser" id="<?php echo $image->anchor ?>">

Comment: I also tried to use in a post with a plugin that allows php in posts but it didn't work yet... I also replaced "cdtrack" with the name of my gallery

Comment: Did you echo the function output? `echo wp75475_imagelist();`

Comment: I did, but no luck yet

Comment: is there any other way?